# What's the difference between a SparseMultigraph<V, E> and a SparseGraph<V, E>?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, algorithm, function

I'm using JUNG2 library and they have 2 similar Graphs which are:

- SparseMultigraph
- SparseGraph

Can someone tell me the differences between them?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the class(es) almost tell it.

- [`SparseMultigraph`](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/SparseMultigraph.html) is a multigraph, which means that there might be multiple (>= 1) or zero edges between two vertices. The `SparseMultigraph` class implements the [`Multigraph`](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/MultiGraph.html) interface.
- [`SparseGraph`](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/SparseGraph.html) is a graph, which means that there is exactly `0` or exactly `1` edge between any two vertices. The `SparseGraph` class doesn't not implement the `Multigraph` interface, but only the `Graph` interface.
- Both classes extend the `AbstractGraph` class.

More info:

- [What is a Multigraph?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph)

Comment: The ’Graph’ which is implemented by ’SparseGraph’ does not explicit prohibit parallel edges but it is likely that this is implicit because ’MultiGraph’ does not extend ’Graph’ in JUNG2.

Answer (score 1):

I think `SparseGraph<V, E>` does not support parallel edges.

while `SparseMultigraph<V, E>` allows parallel edges.

Multigraph: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph